# What does Baudelaire's handwriting say on this first edition frontispiece of 'Les Fleurs du Mal'?

Tags: sens, orthographe

[image: Frontispiece]

Other resolutions are available: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Fleurs_du_mal.jpg

Comment: There is a lot of handwriting. So, you need to be specific otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: I don't think 'all the handwriting on this one page' is too broad of a question, but I'm new here. It's a well defined question that can be (has already been) answered in the space of a brief reply. Is it seriously preferable to split this up into six or seven questions: "What does the handwriting say in the bottom right?"; "What does the handwriting say in the top left?". Perhaps handwriting identification is off-topic?

Comment: @Kiteration There is no problem with your question. It is not "too broad", you are not asking to translate a complete manuscript. That's just a few sentences very difficult to decipher by someone not used to this type of writing. Moreover, both the author of these notes and the subject they deal with are perfectly on topic here. We almost hear Baudelaire speaking in real life!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Les Fleurs du mal
> par (très petit)
> Charles Baudelaire

> Que penseriez-vous de supprimer le mot poësies ?
> Quant à moi, cela me choque beaucoup.

> rouge(?)

> Orthographe vérifiée sur Les Tragiques

> execrables
> exécrables

> Resuscité est bien bizarre.
> Ne serait-ce pas une faute d'impression ?
> Prenez-y garde.
> Quoi, pas même d'accent aigu ?
> Je comprends bien que c'est une orthographe latine, mais comment prononçait-on dans ce temps là ?

> Je juge inutile de vous donner un bon à tirer. Faites ce que vous voudrez.

> Il est clair que *Les Fleurs du mal* sont des poésies; le mot *par* remplaçant *poésies* serait beaucoup mieux.

Comment: I see a period after "garde", which also makes a lot more sense:
"Prenez-y garde. Quoi, pas même d'accent aigu ?"

Comment: @Jhyn C'est vrai, merci !